# Python check operation calculator

Tags: python, calculator

I want to check operator and result print only as number, not in brackets. But I do not know how to add it in my code. Ideally check numbers as float.

```
    texts = ["give first number: ",
         "give operator: ", "give second number: "]
allowed_operators = ['+', '-', '/', '*', '**', '%']


def calculate(value_list):
    #[ 1, "+", 1]
    num1, operator, num2 = value_list

    if operator == '+':
        return num1 + num2
    elif operator == '-':
        return num1 - num2
    elif operator == '*':
        return num1 * num2
    elif operator == '**':
        return num1 ** num2
    elif operator == '/':
        return num1 / num2
    elif operator == '%':
        return num1 % num2
    

last_result = None
while True:

    values = [] 
    i = 0
    
    while i < 3:
        value = input("give value: ")

        if value == "q":
            exit(0)

        if value in allowed_operators:
            values.append(value)  # [+]
        else:
            values.append(float(value))

        
        if value in allowed_operators and i == 0:
            if last_result == None:     
                print("Last calculation does not exist. ")
                continue
            else:
                values.insert(0, last_result)
                i += 1      
        i += 1

    print(values)

    result = calculate(values)

    print(f'Result: {result}')
    last_result = result
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic Python calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850957/basic-python-calculator)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to print the intermediate calculation without brackets then change

```
print(values)
```

to

```
print(" ".join(str(value) for value in values))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you need, but the calculation function can use operator module:

```py
import operator


def calculate(value_list):
    # [ 1, "+", 1]
    num1, flag, num2 = value_list
    flag_func = {'+': 'add', '-': 'sub', '*': 'mul', '**': 'pow', '/': 'truediv', '%': 'mod'}
    if func := flag_func.get(flag):
        return getattr(operator, func)(num1, num2)
    raise Exception(f'Invalid operate {flag=}')
```